# Paypal Direct Payment API using Paypal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-ipn, paypal-soap

is it possible to make a payment with user's paypal balance using Direct Payment? I know that Direct Payment offers recurring payments but I'd like to use it not only for credit cards but for paypal account balance too. Is it possible or not at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the Express Checkout paypal api allows it...

Check out the documentation for paypal's Express Checkout

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPGettingStarted

I do not believe that the Direct Payment option allows it at all.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I assumed. Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: @FlexJack how did you integrate the express checkout with paypal.